# Docker node.js-alpine does not cache DNS results

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, networking, dns

We tried to load test our (dockerized and deployed to AWS ECS) Node.js app, the metrics show that CPU and Memory are quite fine in our containers, but the DNS resolving starts timeouting on bigger load (~600 requests per second, we need to achieve about 30000)

This is the error (we are using http-proxy module, but this should be out of scope of it):

```
// I have renamed the URL to xxx.com
"err": {
    "code": "EAI_AGAIN",
    "errno": "EAI_AGAIN",
    "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
    "hostname": "xxx.com",
    "host": "xxx.com",
    "port": 80,
    "statusCode": 500,
    "stack": "Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN xxx.com:80\n    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)\n    at errnoException (dns.js:55:15)\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)"
},
```

I was thinking that DNS is cached for a few minutes automatically by OS, but this is not happening.

We are using official Node.js docker image 8.9.4-alpine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confirmed, switching to -slim version solved the problem